# ODK-Making Sure That Values Equal To 100%

Tags: odk

I have three questions in a form I'm designing that's concerned with percentage values. Now, I need to make sure that the total of the three questions should not exceed 100. How do I do this? I'm currently using Kobo Form Designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a constraint expression to your prompt.

```
constraint="(/data/int1 + /data/int2 + /data/int3) <= 100"
```